# Flutter: How can i retrieve a file object from an image provider?

Tags: flutter, file

I'm trying to develop an AR application with ARCore. I want to do so that when I take the screenshot of the current AR Scene it will display that image in a Modal Bottom Sheet widget and when you press "Share" it will display that image as a post in a different Feed Page. The screenshot feature provided by the ARCore library stores the screenshot as an Image Provider but I want to pass this image as a File object in order to store it in the Fire Storage so I can share it with the Cloud Firestore Database. How can I retrieve a File object from an ImageProvider?

```
MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () => onUploadPost(context, currentPicture),
            color: lightColor,
            child: Text(
              "Paylaş",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: darkColor,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
          )



Future<void> onTakeScreenshot(BuildContext context) async {
       var image = await arSessionManager!.snapshot();
       editPostSheet(context, image);
}

Future<void> onUploadPost(BuildContext context, File currentImage) async {
       final imagesRef = storageRef.child("Images/");
       UploadTask uploadTask = imagesRef.putFile(currentImage);
       late String url;
       uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
         url = await imagesRef.getDownloadURL();
       }).catchError((onError) {
         print(onError);
       });
       Post newPost =
           Post(author: "Ada", image: url, place: "Kayaköy", userUID: "1");
        db
           .collection("Posts")
           .withConverter(
             fromFirestore: Post.fromFirestore,
             toFirestore: (Post post, options) => post.toFirestore(),
           )
           .add(newPost);
     }
```